# How to prevent setting a state variable to another state variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a controlled component that I call Note. I want its default value to be equal to the selected note (which is set in App.js and passed through as a prop). It seems redundant/bad practice. Here's my code, simplified to the relevant parts. How can I set the default value of textarea to be equal to another state variable?

Edit: Forgot to mention that selectedNote is changed in another component. It works for the state set in useEffect but not for the updates.

App.js

```
function App(){
  const [selectedNote, setSelectedNote] = useState("")
    
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(){
      let req = await fetch("http://localhost:9292/notes");
      let res = await req.json();
      setSelectedNote(res[0])
    }
    fetchData()
  },[])

  return (
    <Note selectedNote={selectedNote.body}/>
  )
}
```

Note.js

```
function Note({selectedNote}) {
  const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState(selectedNote)

  return (
    <form>
      <textarea value={editValue} onChange={handleChange}>
      </textarea>
    </form>
  )
}
```

(To clarify, I have no issues if I write `const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState("testing123")` or some other string)

Comment: On the initial render there's no such thing as `selectedNote.body`. I would probably maintain all of the notes in state, and then [life state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so that `Note` doesn't do any work.

Comment: @Andy Probably bad practice but selectedNote.body is an object value received from my fetch request, being passed in as selectedNote to the other component

Comment: On the initial render you're _not_ passing in an object value because _there is no object_,

Comment: @Andy lifting state up is a good idea, I'm gonna try restructuring a bit. Also I should correct myself -- selectedNote.body is a string

Comment: @itsagift what @Andy is saying is that since you initialize `selectedNote` with `useState("")` on the first render it has no `body` property (*until the fetch is resolved*) so it will pass `undefined` to the `Note`.

Comment: @Gabriele Ah I'll change that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So ideally you want to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.htm) so that the parent component manages the state updates, and the `Notes` component is as dumb as possible.

In this example the data is loaded into state, and then the notes are built, only receiving an id, some body text which will be their value, and an `onChange` handler.

When the text is changed, the state is copied, the object in the array (defined by the id) updated, and the new array pushed back into state.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const json = '[{"id":1,"body":"Note1"},{"id":2,"body":"Note2"},{"id":3,"body":"Note3"}]';

function mockApi() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(json), 2000);
  });
}

function Example() {

  const [ notes, setNotes ] = useState([]);
  const [ selectedNote, setSelectedNote ] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    mockApi()
      .then(res => JSON.parse(res))
      .then(data => setNotes(data));
  }, []);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { value, dataset: { id } } = e.target;
    const copy = [...notes];
    copy[id - 1].body = value;
    setNotes(copy);
  }
  
  function handleClick() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(notes));
  }
  
  if (!notes.length) return 'Loading';

  return (
    <div>
      {notes.map(note => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={note.id}
            id={note.id}
            body={note.body}
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />
        )
      })}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        View state
      </button>
    </div>
  );

}

function Note({ id, body, handleChange }) {
  return (
    <textarea
      data-id={id}
      value={body}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for writing out the example! I used to do this sort of thing, and then someone told me that state should ideally be defined in the component that uses it instead of in the parent. I'm not sure if it was bad advice or if I misunderstood.

Comment: It depends on the use case. Eventually you might migrate to other state management solutions like Redux or Recoil. What that person told you then becomes moot.

Comment: I guess this was the sort of thing I saw that pushed me to define editValue in Note: "A core concept behind React is that every piece of data lives in only one place: the state of the lowest common ancestor of every component"

Comment: We all started somewhere @itsagift. Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

You can provide a function to `useState` that will only be invoked once, when the component renders. Use that function to copy the prop value into the Note's private state.

```js
const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState(() => selectedNote)
```

You may have other problems, such as the prop value being blank on initial render, but this is still usually the most straightforward way to initialize a private state var based on a prop.

If it turns out that blank-initial-state is an insurmountable problem, then you may instead need to set up a `useEffect` that updates the private state when the prop value changes to a satisfactory value. Something like this:

```js
const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState()
React.useEffect(() => {
    // only update state if old is blank & new is not
    if(!editValue && selectedNote) setEditValue(selectedNote)
}, [selectedNote])
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'm still getting this error: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'editValue'. It's not updating

Comment: To clarify, it's now able to update the text in textarea. But the default text in textarea is not updating after I select a new selectedNote. If I get rid of the !editvalue conditional, it updates after I select a new selectedNote, but I can no longer edit the textarea like a controlled component.

Comment: Found a solution: I had to create an "editing" boolean which is set to true when the first change is made and check if that was false instead of editValue.